# finite sum over a Gaussian

Tags: summation, exponential-function

I have a sum of the form:

$$\sum_{n,m=-N}^N e^{-\alpha (n-m)^2}$$

where $\alpha > 0$ is some constant, and $n,m$ take the integer values: $-N,..,N$.
I know there is a possibility of exchanging the "variable of summation" by introducing some "relative coordinates" $\tau = n-m$ and $\eta = \frac{m+n}{2}$, by I don't know how to continue from there.

Thank you

Comment: Why not use $\eta=m+n$, so $\eta\in\mathbb{Z}$? It might help to draw an image of the square lattice of points $(n,m)$ and then of the corresponding points $(\tau,\eta)$ to discover the pattern.

Comment: The question needs some context, it is not clear what you hope to achieve. Is there some limit for $N$ to infinity? Is $α$ negative, small or large? You can order the sum for equal differences $n-m$, but more seems not possible.

Comment: @LutzL for a certain $N$ at fixed $\tau$ you can count how many allowed values $\eta$ has, which gives an explicit prefactor for each term $e^{\alpha\tau^2}$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with my last sentence. You get some kind of "witch hat" function as the coefficient.

Comment: Yes I forgot about the sign of $\alpha$ (changed it in the message now). What I would like to get is some simple expression which is the result of the sum. For example if I had $\sum_\tau e^{-\alpha \tau}$ then the result is simple by using a sum of geometric series.. But here it's not the case. About $N$, I would prefer if it stayed finite, but if there is some nice result when its infinite, than its OK too.

Comment: You can compare the sum to $\int \max(0,N-|x|)e^{−αx^2}\,dx$. But I do not see that you can find a closed expression for it or the sum.

Comment: If $N\rightarrow \infty$ is it possible to approximate in sum way the gaussian sum to a guassian integral?

Answer (score 0):

As @LutzL said, it might be difficult to get a closed form, but you can simplify it at least down to a single sum.

Using the transformation $(\tau,\eta)=(n-m,n+m)$, your grid is modelled by going over the values
$$\tau=-2N,-2N+1,...,2N\\
\eta=-K(\tau),-K(\tau)+2,...,K(\tau)$$ where $K(\tau)=2N-|\tau|$. So you have
$$f(N)=\sum_{\tau=-2N}^{2N}e^{-\alpha\tau^2}\sum_{\eta=-K(\tau)}^{K(\tau),+2}1$$ where the second sum goes over every second number, denoted by the superscript $(+2)$. Now you can simplify this by using $K(-\tau)=K(\tau)$ to
$$\sum_{\tau=-2N}^{2N}e^{-\alpha\tau^2}\sum_{\eta=-K(\tau)}^{K(\tau),+2}1 = 
2\sum_{\tau=1}^{2N}e^{-\alpha\tau^2}\sum_{\eta=-K(\tau)}^{K(\tau),+2}1 +
e^0\sum_{\eta=-K(0)}^{K(0),+2}1$$

Finally, if you use
$$\sum_{\eta=-k}^{k,+2}1=k+1,$$
you get to
$$f(N)=(2N+1)+2(2N+1)\sum_{\tau=1}^{2N}e^{-\alpha\tau^2}-2\sum_{\tau=1}^{2N}\tau e^{-\alpha\tau^2}.$$ If you define $$S_N(\alpha):=\sum_{\tau=1}^{2N}e^{-\alpha\tau^2},$$ your result can be written as

$$f(N)=(2N+1)(1+2S_N(\alpha))+\frac{1}{\alpha}S_N'(\alpha).$$

**Edit** According to the comments [on this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688558/find-the-sum-of-exponentails-of-squares-sum-r-1n-e-alpha-r2), there is no closed form solution for $S_N(\alpha)$, but if you want to do numerics, you might be lucky and find a fast implementation, which makes it applicable for you.

Comment: I am too unexperienced in solving for $S_N(\alpha)$, but as I am very intersted, I posted it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688558/find-the-sum-of-exponentails-of-squares-sum-r-1n-e-alpha-r2) as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Since integrals are [continuous sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum),

$$S\simeq\int_{-N}^N\underbrace{\int_{-N}^Ne^{-\alpha(x-y)^2}dx}_\text{The Gaussian Integral}dy\simeq\int_{-N}^N\sqrt\frac\pi\alpha dy=2N\sqrt\frac\pi\alpha$$

To be more specific,

$$\begin{align}0<\alpha<2.5&\iff S\simeq2N\sqrt{\frac\pi\alpha}
\\\\\\\\\\
3<\alpha<3.5&\iff S\simeq2N\sqrt{\frac\pi{\alpha-\frac12}}
\\\\\\\\\\
\alpha>4&\iff S\simeq2N\end{align}$$

On a related note, $\displaystyle\vartheta_3(0,a)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a^{n^2}$ is the [Jacobi theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function). See [also](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html).