# Find the sum of exponentails of squares $\sum_{r=1}^n e^{-\alpha r^2}$

Tags: summation, generating-functions, closed-form, recursion

I would like to find

$$a_n =\sum_{r=1}^n e^{-\alpha r^2},\qquad \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$$

I tried to solve the equivalent recursion

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+e^{-\alpha n^2}\quad(n>0),\qquad a_0=0.$$

with an ordinary generating function $G(z)=\sum a_n z^n$, for which I came to

$$G(z)(1-z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}e^{-\alpha n^2}z^n.$$ But from there on I got stuck.

Comment: There is no closed form for these finite sums. The sum of the full series is an elliptic function (but this is not much more than giving a name to the result).

Comment: Can you give me background information, which elliptic function it is? Does it equal this elliptic function just by it's definition, or does it have to be proven?

Comment: Mere definition, as already said. For an entry, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function

Comment: Or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function.

Comment: I have not heard theta functions called elliptic functions before.

Comment: @GEdgar Probably a mistake on my part.

Comment: In a neighborhood of zero and for $\alpha>0$ we have that $$S_\alpha(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} e^{-\alpha n^2 x^2} \sim\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi/\alpha}}{x}-1\right).$$